# Element to change doesn't exist when mouseover

Tags: jquery

In not using a CSS3 transition, I've written myself into a bit a hole.  Using the code below, sometimes a mouseleave event is triggered during an animation and the element I want to change does not exist.

I realise my options are probably quite limited (have read through the check mouseover options) but I thought it would be worth an ask just in case..

```
$(".flip_item").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('img:first').stop(true,true).fadeTo(500, 0.5);
    $(this).find('._vis').stop(true,true).fadeTo(500,1);
    }).mouseleave(function(){

    if (!$(this).find('img:first').length || !$(this).find('._vis').length){
    //please let there be an answer that would go here..    
    }

    $(this).find('img:first').stop(true,true).fadeTo(500, 1);
    $(this).find('._vis').stop(true,true).fadeTo(500, 0);    
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle or similar.

Comment: Without your HTML markup, this is fairly useless.